# Ag grid Icon headers

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to add an icon column for one of the column using Ag grid. Unfortunately, I did not get a clue to add icon for the column header directly into grid Options.

**Expected result is**

[image]

**Actual result is**

[image]   Header icon is not coming

**Component TS**

```
 this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([
        {
        headerName: "",
        field: "markedAsFavorite",
        minWidth: 50,
        maxWidth: 50,
        headerComponentParams: { menuIcon: "fa-star" },
        cellRendererFramework: AgGridCustomCellComponent,
        cellRendererParams: {
          ngTemplate: this.markAsFavourite
        }
          }
        ]);
```

Expert advise please?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `headerComponentParams` as described here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/

```
this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs([         
   {
    headerName: "",
    field: "markedAsFavorite",
    minWidth: 50,
    maxWidth: 50,
    headerComponentParams: { template: '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>' },
    cellRendererFramework: AgGridCustomCellComponent,
    cellRendererParams: {
      ngTemplate: this.markAsFavourite
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: do u know how to get header name + the icon to the right ? looked everywhere and cant find it

Comment: Try applying a float right to the template. Might work

Comment: Like this ? headerComponentParams: { template: '<i class="fa fa-star" style="float:right;" ></i>' },

Dont think it work, Idk how to get the headername to get in the template lol params.value wont work

Answer (score 0):

To show the icon, you need to give **components** property `components: { agColumnHeader: CustomHeader }` to the grid instance and create custom header function. Follow the link [ag-grid-header-component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#example-header-component).

Answer (score -2):

first refer to [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering/)

in your cell

```
 {
    headerName: "",
    field: "icon",
    width: 100,
    cellRenderer: function(params) {
        return '<span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>';
    }
}
```

Comment: In your sample code, only cells are rendering,  column header icon is not loading....

Comment: That code only changes column cells but not the header.